# Orchard CMS move site to tenancy

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I have finished creating two Orchard CMS websites. After looking into production hosting on Azure, I have decided I would like to host them in one of two ways:

- As tenants of a single master site
- Using a table prefix to share the SQL Server database

I know during initial set up you can specify a table prefix to allow multiple sites in one database. Is it possible to do this after initial set up? Will I have to set up a new site and then export/import all my data into the new site with the prefixed tables?

Is it possible to migrate a site to be a tenant? Or is this similar to above; create a new site and import all the data into the tenant?

Comment: Export and import is your best bet.

Comment: I thought that'd be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Bertrand's comment, I created a new site with two tenants. I used the same SQL Server database with table prefixes. I exported all the data from my two sites and imported them into the tenants.

One thing I had to do was to delete the cache.dat file in App_Data and restart the website.